# Actionbar bad layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a deployed application which has as a minimum API level 14 (4.1.0).
I develop with an api of 16 (4.4.2)

The action bar I have should look like this :

[image]

However, I have been contacted by a user (the one with 4.1.2) and it has this look (taken from a photo sent by the user) :
[image]

The action bar menu definition uses standard menu elements (icons / actionLayout).
In addition, this layout is displayed upon user request, when taping on a previous menu/actionbar item. The actionbar is then displayed by invalidating the existing one with `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

The menu is then inflated via :

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(iMenuResource, menu);
```

Is this a known problem ?
Is there a workaround for it ?

I hope someone will be able to help here ...

---

Source of the problem seems to have been found.

The second icon in the bar is a custom control with special behaviour. Even though it handles `onMeasure` seemingly correctly, it gets passed a width value far greater than the requested size.

It requests 96dp and yet receives the width of the actionbar.
Is this a querk of android 4.1.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem occurs in 4.1.2 and not later (it would appear), the solution is quite simply to force a maximum width within `onMeasure`.

Even though this would appear to be a rather ungraceful workaround, it is the best I have come up with.